# MAMP Unable to Connect to MySQL on localhost (10061) - 2017

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a dynamic drop down list by requesting data from my database using MAMP.

One of the tutorials I have tried has been talked about already and my version of the code is the same.  [Dynamic dropdown list with PHP & MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154810/dynamic-dropdown-list-with-php-mysql)

Although I am under the impression MAMP has a SQL server, I thought the problem was because I didn't have MySQL installed on my computer so I downloaded it, to no avail.

I went into my Task Manager and tried looking for "MySQL service" although I couldn't find the exact tag I did see MySQL Writer is running, but the Browser and Agent INFLOW is not and refuse to start.

I went here into my computer ( c://windows/system32/drivers/etc.host ) and took off the #s that were before

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

making sure each remained on a separate line, I restarted my computer but I still can't seem to connect.

Any suggestions on how I may be able to fix this?  I am extremely new to PHP and even newer to MySQL so, if possible, please try to keep any solutions simplified so I can follow along.

Comment: you should check your services for MySQL using runnig "services.msc" or "compmgmt.msc"
if the service is there and running, you can query the database with "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin" 
this is just for troubleshooting, it could be the service is running in another port, or not installed at all, a firewall,etc. You have a lot to read.

Comment: Yes, I guess so.  :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue actually was but I ditched MAMP and installed XAMPP and everything seems to be working now.