# PHP - SQL Dynamic Drop down list for existing dates (Months)

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, date

**Aim**

Create a dynamic drop down list of months based on existing dates within the database.

**Database**

[image]

**Existing User Interface**

[image]

**Codes of Existing (UI)**

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 prod-filter" align="right">
 <font size="4.5" color=""><span class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-1x"></span>
        <b>Year & Month: </b>
    </font>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="selectyear" data-width="100px">
    <?php
      $sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT year(MonthYear) as MonthYear FROM dateDatabase";
      $sqltran = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
        echo "<option value='".$rowList["MonthYear"]."'>" .$rowList["MonthYear"]. "</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
    <select class="selectpicker" id="selectmonth" data-width="120px">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
```

**Existing UI Description**

The existing user interface only has dynamic drop down for the existing years but not for the Months as the months are hard-coded as shown in the existing codes. The Database contains dates for years 2016, 2017, and 2018, and as shown in the Existing UI Image, only those years are prompted into the drop down.

**Desired User Interface**

[image]

**Desired UI Description**

The desired user interface will have a dynamic drop down for the existing months. For example, as shown in the database image, 2018 has data for only the first 2 months, which are January and February therefore the after selecting 2018 for the **YEAR** drop down, the Months drop down should only show January and February.

Another example, if 2017 only has data for the Months, March, July, August, October, and December, the user will only be able to select those months after selecting the Year 2017.

**Tried out Codes**

```
<!-- Time period selection -->
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 prod-filter" align="right">
         <font size="4.5" color=""><span class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-1x"></span><!-- icon for "Select your department" -->
                <b>Time Period: </b><!-- name of dropdownlist -->
            </font>
          <select class="selectpicker" id="selectyear" data-width="100px">
            <?php
              $sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT year(MonthYear) as MonthYear FROM dateDatabase";
              $sqltran = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
              while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
                echo "<option value='".$rowList["MonthYear"]."'>" .$rowList["MonthYear"]. "</option>";
              }
            ?>
          </select>
            <select class="selectpicker" id="selectmonth" data-width="120px">
            <?php
              $sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME (month, (MonthYear)) as MonthYear FROM dateDatabase WHERE EXISTS(SELECT month(MonthYear) FROM dateDatabase)";
              $sqltran = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
              while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
                echo "<option value='".$rowList["MonthYear"]."'>" .$rowList["MonthYear"]. "</option>";
              }
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
```

I tried writing the distinct but it didn't generate the existing months. It still generated all the months in numbers. So I thought of adding in the DATENAME to generate the names but that only displayed "Nothing Select"

[image]

Comment: This is a specification and _not a question_ **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for commenting and not down voting straight away. I'll add in the codes that I tried out.

Comment: And **WHO** thinks a specification question deserves an upvote. Please get real

Comment: Seems like you have already coded a HUGH CLUE for yourself. So for your month dropdown do the same as for the Year but use `DISTINCT MONTH(MonthYear) as validMonths`

Comment: @FirstOne Oh, right, I do beg your pardon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the year select value `.change()` send ajax request to db and select data base on the selected year.

```
$('#selectyear').on('change', function () {
    $.post('demo.php', {year: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#selectmonth').empty();
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            $('#selectmonth')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",value)
                    .text(value));
        });
    })
})
```

Then in your PHP

```
<?php 
include "dbconnection.php"; 
$year = trim($_POST['year']); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dateDatabase WHERE YEAR(MonthYear) = $year"; 

$months = []; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $months[] = date('F', strtotime($row['MonthYear'])); 
    }
} else {
    $months[] = "0 result";
}
echo json_encode($months);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Julekgwa thanks for helping out and sorry for the late reply but unfortunately it didn't work....I guess I've made a mistake somewhere. Should I replace the `value` at `.attr("value",value)` with `$months` at `echo json_encode($months);` ?

Comment: Well the only error was that the dropdown list for months was "Nothing Selected"

Comment: can you add `console.log(data);` in the ajax code, and see what it prints.

Comment: Alright, I've added it and it says that my PHP file can't be found. But I did replace the `("demo.php',` with my PHP file which is existingMonths.php. `POST http://localhost/projecthealthassist/existingMonths.php 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: double check your spelling, and check if the file exist, paste your code here https://codeshare.io/GkKyoA, use `$.post('existingMonths.php',` if the files are in the same directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161660/discussion-between-theemployee123-and-julekgwa).

Answer (score 1):

Your Error is within your query. DATENAME is a MSSQL Function and not for Mysql. Try MONTH() and MONTHNAME() instead. As example:

```
<?php
  $sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(MonthYear) as MonthNumber,  MONTHNAME(MonthYear) as MonthName FROM dateDatabase";
  $sqltran = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
    echo "<option value='".$rowList["MonthNumber"]."'>" .$rowList["MonthName"]. "</option>";

  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on that. I've just checked it out. But no months was generated, only "Nothing Selected"

Comment: That is because you are actually nothing selecting. I miss the following in your code: the jquery call, and the actually response for it.

this looks like a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154810/dynamic-dropdown-list-with-php-mysql